# lxml package on macOS Xcode request

Tags: python, xcode, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I tried to install the package "lxml" on macOS but I get an error message and now I am block:

```
ERROR: b"xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.\n"
```

Is it mandatory to install the Xcode software to install lxml? 
I would avoid it, if possible.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `lxml` is created in `C/C++` and probably it needs compiler. How did you tried to install it? `pip install lxml`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was following a tutorial to understand how to scrape data with BeautifulSoup and the process requires "lxml" package

Comment: you can uses standard module `html.parser` instead of `lxml` and you will not have to install it. Use `BeautifulSoup(..., "html.parser")` and it will also work. Only sometimes `html.parser` has problem with incorrect HTML. Information about parsers in [BeautifulSoup doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). **EDIT:** correction: it has to be `html.parser`, not `http.parser`.